# How can i add a dialog which will show a particular file details?

Tags: java, android

### I want to add a button to my android application i.e. 'Show details'

On clicking this button, we will see a dialog with the following details about a certain file:

1. Name
2. Path
3. Size
4. Date Modified
5. Date created

*Example of the dialog*

[image: This is just an example of how my dialog should look]

Till Now, I have figured the Name, Path, Size property and also the last modified date but I am unable to understand how can I implement the date created property.

```
private void showDetails(String fileName){

    File file = new File(fileName);
    String filePath = file.getParent();
    double fileSize = file.length();
    long creationDate = file.lastModified();

    Date dateCreated = new Date(creationDate);
    new MaterialDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .title(R.string.creating_pdf)
            .content("File Name: " + file.getName() +"\nFile Path: " + filePath + "\nFile Size: " + fileSize/(1000*1000) + " Mb\nFile Created On: " + dateCreated)
            .show();

}
```

My questions:

1. How can I retrieve date along with the time of creation?
2. Is`file.lastModified()` the right way to get the last modified date and time?
3. Is this the right way to implement a Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.creating_pdf);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("File Name: " + file.getName() +"\nFile Path: " + filePath + "\nFile Size: " + fileSize/(1000*1000) + " Mb\nFile Created On: " + dateCreated);


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Fix Date", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Or you can make a custom layout for dialog view

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
    text.setText(msg);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how i can fetch both creation and last modified date?